# Google Play Store Unsupported Devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, android-manifest

I published my app on Google Play Store. However, Google Play Console tells me that almost 4000 Android devices do not support my app. It runs perfectly on Samsung and LG phones but when it comes to some Sony, Asus or Xiaomi models, the app can't be installed and run. I am attaching AndroidMAnifest.xml below for you to see and check what i am doing wrong. Would anyone please help me figure out what the problem is? (By the way permissions may seem unnecessary but i did not add them on purpose. They were automatically written after i imported Admob plugins. I will remove them anyway but can it be the problem?)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="2"
    package="com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx"
    platformBuildVersionCode="27"
    platformBuildVersionName="8.1.0">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />

    <application
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f090168"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f050029"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f020054"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:banner="@ref/0x7f020053"
        android:isGame="true">

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f050029"
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:screenOrientation="6"
            android:configChanges="0x40002fff">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x0103000f"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0xfb0" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@ref/0x7f0b0001" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030007"
            android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x40000fff"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030007"
            android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x40000fff"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.build-id"
            android:value="14f52ffd-ad31-4575-ba0c-76977716c5ac" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="true" />
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x20000" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.vulkan"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: And also on some of the phones, the app was installed successfully but then it gave a black screen when i tried to run it..

Comment: that is probably because of `android:glEsVersion="0x20000"` and `android:minSdkVersion="16"`. Not all devices support opengles 2.0, and not all devices have Android sdk 16

Comment: Yeah sure. But i am using Unity Editor so the minimum SDK version number than i can use is 16. However, i am sure that the phones that i used to run the game had higher API levels like 7.0, 4.4 and so on..  @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: then it is just OK for you to see those 4000 unsupported devices.

Comment: please show your gradle file.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Not really, those 4000 devices are pretty new and have APIs higher than 16. So SDK number being 16 is not the reason.

Comment: @DnyaneshwarPanchal Sorry if I am missing a point. Do you think gradle file might be replaced by another file when the app is designed by Unity? Because i couldn't find gradle file although i analyzed the APK by Android Studio. Instead, I have some cpp libraries like libmain.so , libmono.so and libunity.so. Would you please clarify that point? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Were you able to figure this out, ever? @Cagri

Answer (score 0):

Try with this permissions.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out but why you think that the app requires those features?

Comment: Declared <uses-feature> elements are informational only, meaning that the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing an application. However, other services (such as Google Play) or applications may check your application's <uses-feature> declarations as part of handling or interacting with your application. For this reason, it's very important that you declare all of the features that your application uses.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks a lot! I will try it out, but the problem is not just the fact that Google Play shows some unsupported devices but the app is actually unsupported by some phones(experimentally proved).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that these devices don't support your app. Without knowing anything about devices I can't say for sure but you have a few things in your manifest affecting which devices it targets:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16" ...
```

Any devices with SDK lower than 16 won't run your app.

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x20000" />
```

Any device with an older version of OpenGL won't run your app. You just have to accept this, if this is a requirement of Unity. You game just won't run on some older phones.