# Unity AR foundation, only 601 supported devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

I have a Unity app that uses AR foundation.
When I upload a build to the Google play store, its says it only supports 601 devices. My own phone (A samsung galaxy s7) which I have been testing on, and on which the app is running fine, is not even supported.

I have tried setting a custom main manifest but there is almost nothing in the AndroidManifest.xml file when it gets created, nothing concerning looking anyway..

I have also tried uploading builds with both "Depth" and "Requirement" set to optional in the AR Core settings in XR plugin management. I still get only the 601 supported devices.

I actually have a similar AR foundation app already on the play store that supports over 1000 devices including my phone.
The only difference I can make out is that my new app targets API levl 31, whereas the old one targets 29. ... 31 is the minimum target now on google play so I cant even upload a build targeting 29 now.

Unity version is 2021.3.9f1

AR foundation + Ar Core package versions are 4.2.3

Here are the details from an upload with both "Depth" and "Requirement" set to optional in the AR Core settings.
[image]

Comment: What is `minSdkVersion` set to in the different apps?

Comment: 24              (more character for SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the 1st answer from here seemed to do it..

[Google Play Store Unsupported Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974483/google-play-store-unsupported-devices)

Adding these two lines to the empty android manifest made devices go from 601 to  11,673

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```